# RPM meter and send value with serial communication

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, winavr

I have a question about how to reading RPM and send value with serial
It's my code:

```
char init(void)
{
  UBRRH=(uint8_t) (UBRR_CALC>>8);
  UBRRL=(uint8_t) UBRR_CALC;
  UCSRB=(1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
  UCSRC=(1<<URSEL)|(3<<UCSZ0);
  return 0;
}

void send(unsigned char x)
{
  while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE))){}
  UDR=x;
}

void sendstring(char *s)
{
  while(*s)
  {
    send(*s);
    s++;
  }
}

volatile uint16_t count=0;    //Main revolution counter   
volatile uint16_t rps=0;    //Revolution per second

void Wait()
{
  uint8_t i;

  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    _delay_loop_2(0);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  Wait();
  Wait();
  Wait();
  Wait();

  //Init INT0
  MCUCR|=(1<<ISC01);   //Falling edge on INT0 triggers interrupt.
  GICR|=(1<<INT0);  //Enable INT0 interrupt

  //Timer1 is used as 1 sec time base
  //Timer Clock = 1/1024 of sys clock
  //Mode = CTC (Clear Timer On Compare)
  TCCR1B|=((1<<WGM12)|(1<<CS12)|(1<<CS10));

  //Compare value=976
  OCR1A=976;
  TIMSK|=(1<<OCIE1A);  //Output compare 1A interrupt enable

  //Enable interrupts globaly
  sei();

  while(1)
  {
  }
}

ISR(INT0_vect)
{
  //CPU Jumps here automatically when INT0 pin detect a falling edge
  count++;
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  //CPU Jumps here every 1 sec exactly!
  rps=count;
  send(rps);
  count=0;
}
```

Can we send serial data when interrupt counter and timer, i have error when try it ?

And what is the best methode to read RPM and send value with serial

Comment: Your question is somewhat difficult to answer with the amount of information you provided about what you're trying to do. From your other post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408272/) I assume your question is about obtaining the rpm of a brushless motor.

Comment: You might be able to find the answer to your question in [Atmel application note AVR443](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2596-sensor-based-control-of-three-phase-brushless-dc-motors_application-note_avr443.pdf) and the corresponding [sample code](http://www.atmel.com/Images/AVR443.zip).

Comment: What error do you have when you try it?  What doesn't work?  Is it as simple as that you never call init(), thus your UART isn't ready to send?

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem is that rps is defined as int16_t and your send routine is expecting an unsigned char.

Is the range 0-255 high enough for your RPS?

Do you want the RPS to be human readable or are you sending it to another computer or micro-controller?

It is possible to send serial in you interrupt routines but you need to be careful since the serial routines are not usually re-entrant.